# How to get latest build number from another job in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline 2.0, and I would like to get another job's latest successful build number.

What's the pipeline syntax to use?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get it this way

```
def buildNumber = Jenkins.instance.getItem('jobName').lastSuccessfulBuild.number
```

If you get a `RejectedAccessException` you will have to approve those methods, see [In-process Script Approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/#in-process-script-approval)

Comment: Is there some docu for the field `lastSuccessfulBuild`? Couldn't find any mention in Jenkins' official API docs.

Comment: @Florian here you go [Job#getLastSuccessfulBuild](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html#getLastSuccessfulBuild--). It's actually a method but groovy allows it to be invoked in field-like way.

Comment: Consider using `getItemByFullName()` instead of `getItem()`. This can be important if you have folders and the `jobName` is in another folder.

Answer (score 10):

To add to Vitalii's answer, this is in case you're using Multibranch Pipeline Plugin:

```
def buildNumber = Jenkins.instance.getItem('jobName').getItem('branchName').lastSuccessfulBuild.number
```

Answer (score 7):

It's so annoying to get approvals in enterprise environment(a lot of request and approvals)
So I am using following API way to get the latest build number.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
httpRequest url: 'https://jenkinsurl.local/job/Build/api/json', outputFile: 'output.json'

def jsonFile = readFile(file: 'output.json')
def data = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonFile)
latestBuildNumber = "${data.lastSuccessfulBuild.number}"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def build_job = build job: "Build"
build_job_number = build_job.getNumber()
```

Comment: That's going to build the job name specified as "Build" and then get that build number, which isn't what the OP is asking.